# Taking HTML Form data as text, sending them to html2pdf

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2pdf

How do i take and sent this form data as a text/string to the html2pdf function? I want to download the pdf via a css submit button.

Form and JS code:

```
<form action= method=  enctype="text/plain">

    <label for="fname">Adı</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Adınız">

    <label for="lname">Soyadı</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Soyadınız">

    <label for="country">Başvurulacak Birim</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <option value="australia">Pazarlama</option>
      <option value="canada">Sosyal Medya Yönetimi</option>
      <option value="usa">Ürün Tasarımı</option>
    </select>

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Burada kendinizi tanıtın..." style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" onclick="Fonksiyon();" value="İNDİR">

  </form>
             
<script>
                 
function Fonksiyon() {
var element = document.getElementById('element-to-print');
html2pdf(element);
          }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of points -

1. Add `id` to your `form`. Since you are referring it by `element-to-print` in `Fonksiyon` function -

   `<form id ="element-to-print">`
2. Change input type from `submit` to `button` where you call function `Fonksiyon` -

   `<input type="button" onclick="Fonksiyon();" value="İNDİR">`

[Working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/706vw1qb/)

Comment: Now i can download the pdf file. But without data. It only includes html form with empty answers.

Comment: @ats, Please check your html2pdf version used and also make sure you are referring to html2pdf bundle. I am referring to https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.8.1/html2pdf.bundle.js CDN and it works fine.